# Login on production server doesn't work

Tags: php, yii2

On local server it works, but when I try to login on production server I get this message:

```
PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
Array to string conversion    

1. in /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/User.php at line 240
2. in /var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii2/web/User.php – yii\base\ErrorHandler::handleError(8, 'Array to string conversion', '/var/www/html/vendor/yiisoft/yii...', 240, ...) at line 240
3. in /var/www/html/common/models/LoginForm.php – yii\web\User::login(common\models\User, 2592000) at line 59
4. in /var/www/html/frontend/controllers/SiteController.php – common\models\LoginForm::login() at line 81
```

Files on local and production servers are the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 240 from yii2/web/User.php is

```
$log = "User '$id' logged in from $ip with duration $duration.";
```

So see if $id or $ip or $duration is an array. You are doing something wrong someplace.

Can you post what $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] is?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

The problem is with $id.

On localhost returns: 41
On server returns: Array ( ) 1

I made this change:

`die(print_r($id));`

Also, when I change the line to:

`$log = "User logged in from $ip with duration $duration".` 

there is no error. But user is not logged in. Thanks.

Comment: DO NOT modify the core scripts, if you want extend it in your own scripts. search why the $id is an array, you have a bug someplace.

Comment: Thanks. Problem was with primary key.

Comment: `enableSchemaCache` in `db` config array item, set it to `false` if it is set to `true`

Answer (score 7):

It is happening due to the id field in the user database model is not a primary key. Simply add the PK constraint to user->id filed from the database.

**From DB console:**

```
ALTER TABLE `user` ADD PRIMARY KEY(`id`);
```

Or any visual tools like phpMyAdmin there is a primary key add functionality from the "Structure" tab.

Comment: This fixed it for me. No idea why id was not primary key though to begin with. Bad db copy i guess.