# yii2 having trouble with login module in new server

Tags: php, apache, ubuntu, yii2

I have a yii2 application that I have been developing. The login function works as intended on my local WAMP server and a shared hosting server using PHP 5.5 and 5.4 each.

I got an Ubuntu 14.04 server and installed apache 2.7 and php 5.5 on it. The application loads and everything else on the site loads fine, but the login function is not working.

Here is my login code:

```
    public function login()
{
    if ($this->validate())
    {
        // get user status if user exists, otherwise assign not active as default
        $this->status = ($user = $this->getUser()) ? $user->status : User::STATUS_NOT_ACTIVE;

        // if we have active and valid user log him in
        if ($this->status === User::STATUS_ACTIVE) 
        {
            return Yii::$app->user->login($user, $this->rememberMe ? 3600 * 24 * 30 : 0);
        } 
        else 
        {
            return false; // user is not active
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This returns true when I put in the correct credentials, but the application is not shown as logged in. Can anybody tell where I've gone wrong with installing the application? I've tried enabling apache modules and php extensions but can't seem to find anything that works.

Comment: had you checked your error log ? `runtime/application.log`

Comment: check the answer of this question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27681505/login-on-production-server-doesnt-work hope it helps you

Answer (score 0):

For anybody having trouble, It was a permission error on the runtime session folder. I corrected the permissions on /app/runtime and the application is working fine now.